# to create Whiteboard component

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air, flexbuilder

How do I create a simple drawing board/whiteboard functionality in Flex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is opensource solution for your question.

**Blog post**
http://www.jamesward.com/blog/2006/08/16/flex-paint-flex-display-object-to-png/

**Source code at SourceForge**
http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=174131

Answer (score 0):

http://tv.adobe.com/#vi+f1472v1007

This gives more than enough info to get you started